# iOS Swift Tabbar Controller Add Item (new tab) programmatically

Tags: ios, swift3, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

My App have Tab bar Controller, Which have 4 Tab bar items. I need to add one more tab bar item as 5th, is it possible to add new item as programmatically.

Comment: if you add in interface also it comes on more option

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I not get you clearly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `viewDidload` of your first tab(viewController), you can do something like,

```
   self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?.append(viewController)
```

here `viewController` is your 5th tab!